# Select records and fill hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I use ruby 1.8.7. I have method wich select records and fill hash. In my opinion the code is not dry. Could somebody help me to refactor it and make it shorter and more elegant?

```
def fill_attributes()
  if (!$array[:status_id])
            $array[:status_id] = @customer.status_id
             @status_name=Status.find($array[:status_id]).name rescue nil
            $array[:status]=@status_name if @status_name                           
      end

     if (!$array[:color_id])
            $array[:color_id] = @customer.color_id
            @color_name=Color.find($array[:color_id]).name rescue nil
            $array[:color]=@color_name if @color_name
      end
     .....

  end
```

My version is:

```
  map={'model1' => Model1, 'model2' => Model2,'model3' =>Model3}

  map.keys.each do |model|   
       key="#{model}_id".to_sym
       value="#{model}.#{model}_id" 
     if (!$array[key])  
          $array[key] =  #instance_variable_set("@#{value}",eval(value, binding) ) 
          name=map[model].find($array[key]).name rescue nil
          $array[key]=name if name                  
      end
   end
```

But there's a problem, to use `instance_variable_set` I have to create a class? What is the  best way to refactor it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can optimize it like :

```
def fill_attributes()
  if (!$array[:status_id])
    $array[:status_id] = @customer.status_id
    $array[:status]= get_attribute_name('status',$array[:status_id] )
  end

  if (!$array[:color_id])
    $array[:color_id] = @customer.color_id
    $array[:color]= get_attribute_name('color',$array[:color_id] )
  end

end 

Private

def get_attribute_name(relator, relator_id)
  relator = relator.classify.constantize.find(relator_id)
  !relator.nil? ? relator.name : nil
end
```

Hope this will help you .

Comment: Hi, but it does not reduced the code :) almost the same

Comment: Refactoring isn't always about making your code shorter. Your aim is always to make the code easier to understand, or to introduce more flexibility so that you can add a new feature. A refactor often has the effect on increasing your code length (especially if you extract lots of methods). This is not a bad thing if your code becomes easier to read.